# Is there really a rapper named Prix-Mo?

Tags: rap, prog-metal

Supposedly, as Prog-Metal masters Dream Theater were recording their album [*Awake* (1994)](http://dreamtheater.wikia.com/wiki/Awake), a rapper named Prix-Mo was laying down tracks in an adjacent studio.  As the story goes, Dream Theater's drummer Mike Portnoy wandered over and asked Prix-Mo if he wouldn't mind reading a few lines from the book "Cultural Revolution", and this reading was used in an interlude of the song 'Voices'.

I've googled Prix-Mo, and there's absolutely nothing on the Internet I can find on the guy.  Does he really exist, or was this a bit of misinformation passed around the Internet community?  If he exists, has he ever released anything?  Maybe under a different name?

Comment: If you'd actually googled him you'd have found he's also credited on https://www.discogs.com/Animaniacs-A-Hip-hopera-Christmas/release/2914828 . Why wouldn't there have been a rapper called "Prix-Mo" who never became famous? Pop music is full of "failed" artists.

Comment: OK, fair enough, but he was supposedly in the studio cutting tracks.  Where's the result of that?  Surely he'd have one solo album under his belt?  A single?  A wiki page?  Something?

Comment: Prix-Mo ain’t just MPs voice??

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, the rapper probably was cutting tracks at the time this rockstar approached him about doing something with his band and their album. The rapper was probably working on a demo album or something like that to get his career up and going at that time. Now, why haven't we heard of him? well, probably because the rapper was talented in all but sucked at writing rhymes, or maybe his voice wasn't good enough for rapping, I mean there are a lot of possibilities that contribute to this man's failure.